# Mitchell's proof of Gabriel-Popesco theorem

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

The question concerns the following article:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404981900657

The article appears to give a quick proof of Gabriel-Popescu theorem. However, there is a certain step I don't follow regarding the first lemma. Mitchell says that to show that $\phi\circ\mu = 0$ it suffices to prove that $\phi\circ\mu\circ\lambda = 0$ where $\lambda\colon K'\to K, \mu'\colon K'\to \bigoplus_{m \in F} G$ is a pullback of the kernel $\mu\colon K\to \bigoplus_{m \in M} G$ and $\sum_{m \in F} u_m\circ p_m\colon \bigoplus_{m \in F} G \to \bigoplus_{m \in M} G$ ($F$ is a finite subset of $M$, $u_m$ is a coproduct injections for $\bigoplus_{m \in M} G$ and $p_m$ is a product projection for the finite direct sum (i.e. a biproduct) $\bigoplus_{m \in F} M$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Mitchell really means is that to prove that $\phi\circ \mu=0$, it suffices to prove that $\phi\circ \mu\circ \lambda=0$ **for all finite subset** $F$ of $M$.

This is true because $\bigoplus_M G$ is the filtered colimit of all $\bigoplus_F G$, with the arrows $\sum_{m \in F} u_m\circ p_m\colon \bigoplus_{m \in F} G \to \bigoplus_{ M} G$ forming the colimit cocone. Then because the category has the AB5 property, $K$ is also the filtered colimit of all the $K'_F$, with the arrows $\lambda_F$ forming the colimit cocone; in particular, the family of arrows $\lambda_F$ is jointly epimorphic, which explains why it suffices to consider all the composites $\phi\circ \mu\circ \lambda$ to prove that $\phi\circ \mu=0$.